# CherryPy can't display images

Tags: python, google-chrome, windows-7, cherrypy

I tried for about 5 hours now to display a image to my webpage.
My code is like this:

```
import os
import cherrypy

file_path = os.getcwd().replace("\\", "/")

class Home:
    def index(self):
        return """<img src="img/logolong.jpg" alt="Main Page" />"""
    index.exposed = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cherrypy.server.socket_host = "127.0.0.1"
    cherrypy.server.socket_port = 50505
    config = {"/static":
                        {"tools.staticdir.on": True,
                         "tools.staticdir.dir": file_path,
                        },
                      "/images":
                        {"tools.staticdir.on": True,
                        "tools.staticdir.dir": file_path+"/img"}
                    }

    cherrypy.tree.mount(Home(), "/", config=config)
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

I searched everywhere and tried like everything. I'm using Google Chrome and Windows7.

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: This is a question you should be asking the author of CherryPy.

Comment: What happens when you try to access the image directly? Does it 404?

Comment: Aren't you looking for images in `/img/img/logolong.jpg`? The config setting looks like it sets the location of images, so you shouldn't need the `img/` when you reference it in index.

Comment: FYI - you can decorate your handlers to expose them. `@cherrypy.expose` above your `Home` class can replace `index.exposed = True`

Answer (score 1):

Your code exposes logolong.jpg at the URI `/static/images/img/logolong.jpg`, but your HTML is saying it should be at `/img/logolong.jpg`. You need to reconcile those one way or the other. To keep the HTML as it is and fix the config, you should change it to:

```
config = {
    "/img": {
        "tools.staticdir.on": True,
        "tools.staticdir.dir": os.path.join(file_path, "img"),
    }
}
```

(using `os.path.join` in this way means you can get rid of the `replace("\\", "/")` above)

This will serve the *file* `%cd%\\img\\logolong.jpg` at the *URI* `/img/logolong.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line...

```
return """<img src="img/logolong.jpg" alt="Main Page" />"""\
```

to this line...

```
return """<img src="/logolong.jpg" alt="Main Page" />"""
```

Andrew